# word or expression which indicate/signal the option that best matches your goal? the option that comes the closest?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

word, expression, or to a lesser extent (likely ~80% less), a phrase request

---

this is the goal

- a = 60%
- b = 20%
- c = 20%

you're looking for the combination of a, b, c where the net % of each combined would come closest to the goal above

#### **what would indicate/signal the option that best matches your goal? the option that comes the closest?**

---

for instance,

option A

- a = 55% (5% away, missing)
- b = 30% (10% away, missing)
- c = 15% (5% away, missing)

net = 20% away, missing

option B

- a = 62% (2% away, missing)
- b = 18% (2% away, missing)
- c = 20% (0% away, missing)

net = 4% away, missing

**option B is better**

Comment: why is this on hold when ppl already answered it? there nothing clarified about what exactly is unclear, it's hard to know what to fix

Answer (score 1):

**Best fit**

> Mathematics  A line on a graph which best illustrates the relationship
>   between a set of points, especially one drawn so as to minimize the
>   deviations from the line by individual points; frequently attributive.
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/best_fit)

By analogy, the answer that best fits your goal state.  Best fit doesn't mean exact fit, just the option that comes closest.

Comment: so if choosing between an apple and an orange, best fit would be most descriptive?

Comment: @ambw If the goal state is *spherical and orange* then yes, an orange is the best fit.

Comment: any best fit advice or best fit suggestion for what to do when 95% of ppl do understand what is meant by best fit even when you say & explain it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use ***optimum*** (or ***optimal***).

Collins:

> **[optimum](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/optimum)**
>
> *or* **optimal**
>
> *adjective* [usually ADJECTIVE noun]
>
> The **optimum** or **optimal** level or state of something is the best level or
>   state that it could achieve.
>
> [formal]
>
> Aim to do some physical activity three times a week for optimum
>   health.
>
> ...regions in which optimal conditions for farming can be created.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Comment: would ideal work?

Comment: @ambw well, from your example, your _goal_ (60+20+20) is _ideal_ whereas option B is _optimal_ among the available options.

Comment: would best be more descriptive? how about desirable or preferred?